# Single computer on network cannot connect to internet

Tags: windows, internet-connection

I hope you can help me out! :)

I have 3 computers and one device (Xbox) on my home network; 2 running XP and one on Vista.

The computer that can't connect to the internet (XP) is old and failing, and shows no warning before it completely runs out of battery. Thus today, I started it up forgetting that I had unplugged it the night before, and it just ran out of battery entirely whilst I was using it and died.

I think that before this I had been browsing the internet, but I can't remember for certain. (i.e. The problem I am having may or may not have been caused by this 'hard' power off).

Anyway, now when I start the computer up it takes 5-10 minutes after logging on to display the start bar and icons. Also, I cannot browse the internet. The computer seems to connect to the network OK (I have tried both wired and wireless), but I can't visit sites and can't ping web addresses.

Pinging the router fails, as does pinging another of my computers on the network.

I have never encountered something like this before, and whilst I am no noob I am also not a sysadmin, haha. :(

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

P.S. I have tried a system restore (newbie move?).

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things.  What does the output of `ipconfig /all` say?  If you don't have a valid IP address, this could explain why you can't connect to anything.  A valid IP address would look like 192.168.x.x for home networks.

You could also be experiencing winsock corruption.  View the MS article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259) and see if you fit the criteria.  They have a fix you can download to another computer and carry over to the affected computer.

HTH